# Spring inserting filepath to mysql

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm using Spring 3.2, Hibernate 4.1 and Mysql. I'm trying to save a file to the local drive and then save the filepath to the database to be used for future download. I have implemented the file upload to server but now I'm not sure who to go about saving the file path to the mysql table.

This is the controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "save")
public String saveProcess(@RequestParam("moduleId") Integer moduleId, 

@ModelAttribute("module") Module module, BindingResult result, 
@RequestParam("file") CommonsMultipartFile[] file ,
HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) throws   

 IllegalStateException, IOException {
    logger.info("Request to save the module");

    if(module != null){

    if (file != null && file.length > 0) {
         for (CommonsMultipartFile aFile : file){

             System.out.println("Saving file: " + aFile.getOriginalFilename());

             if (!aFile.getOriginalFilename().equals("")) {
                 aFile.transferTo(new File(saveDirectory +    

             aFile.getOriginalFilename()));
             }
         }
     }


     moduleService.saveorupdate(module);

}
    return "redirect:/home";
}
```

This is the db

```
 CREATE TABLE `modules` (
`module_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`document_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`document_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`module_id`);
```

The filepath is to be inserted into the document_path column. Any thoughts would be welcome.

Comment: what's the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm wondering how to now save the filepath of the file which I uploaded to a database table.

Answer (score 0):

First, the module_id is generated by the database, so you shouldn't be accepting it from the front end. What if I send module_id as 24 when you expect the next entry in the DB is 30?

Now the code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "save")
public String saveProcess(@RequestParam("moduleId") Integer moduleId, @ModelAttribute("module") Module module, BindingResult result, @RequestParam("file") CommonsMultipartFile[] file) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
    logger.info("Request to save the module");

    if(module != null) { // No need for the check. Spring guarantees a non null object if it is expected to be a @ModelAttribute. 

    if (file != null && file.length > 0) {
         for (CommonsMultipartFile aFile : file){ 
             Module module = new Module(); //only one file or more? If one then use the @ModelAttribute module.

             if (!"".equals(aFile.getOriginalFilename())) { // Best practice to check equals in reverse to avoid potential NullPointerExceptions.
                 File file = new File(saveDirectory + aFile.getOriginalFilename());
                 aFile.transferTo(file);
                 module.setDocumentTitle(aFile.getOriginalFilename());
                 module.setDocumentPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
                 module = moduleService.saveorupdate(module); // return module or id so that you can set it and pass it to the view.
             }
         }
     }
  }
  return "redirect:/home";
}
```