# How to save an image in Mysql database via spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring

table

```
create table image(
   id int(5) PRIMARY KEY 
   image BLOB
);
```

I have also created a `POJO` class which has both the fields and I have taken an image in byte.

How should I save an image in the DB? My Db is `MySQL`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using spring MultipartFile. Check out this [article](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) for more details. Go through the detailed explanation given there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice is to save the path to the image and not the image as BLOB.

I hope this can help you : [Spring inserting filepath to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658453/spring-inserting-filepath-to-mysql)